# state is present but all of the following are missing: device_type, name in adding new power outlet to netbox

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, netbox

ansible , I'm having a problem with adding new power outlet with netbox . I managed to supply fields such as device type, device role and name, However I am getting the same issue over and over again . "state is present but all of the following are missing: device_type, name". Is there someone who encounter this issue and please share with your solution. Thank you.

here is the query for adding :

```
- name: "Test Netbox modules"
  hosts: netbox
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Create power port within Netbox with only required information
      netbox.netbox.netbox_power_outlet_template:
        netbox_url: "netbox_url"
        netbox_token: "netbox_token"
        data:
          name: PWR-IN (IEC-60320 C14)
          device_type: UPS Battery pack for 5KVA
          device_role: Power Source
        state: present
        validate_certs: False
```